# Simple function suddenly throws "An unknown error has occurred, please try again later"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Since today morning, I am getting the below message while trying to run new App scripts on a new Google sheet.

> Error  An unknown error has occurred, please try again later.

My other App scripts attached to existing Google sheets continue to run fine. But if I create a new sheet and add even a plain simple function as shown below and try to execute this, I get the above error after it attempts to run it for some time and then gives up.

```
function Mytest()
{

}
```

I suspect that it is not able to bring the permission box which it use to bring up for any new script created. Till yesterday, once the permissions dialog box comes up and I used to give the permissions, the scripts use to run fine. But today it is not even bringing up the permission dialog box.

Comment: Try using another container

Comment: sorry, what you meant by another container?

Comment: Try using another spreadsheet

Comment: Have tried that also but same issue.

Comment: You can always try the old cliche Ctrl-Alt-Delete and reboot your computer.  That has worked for me in the past when I had a similar issue.

Comment: try different browser, I had the problem with old firefox

Answer (score 4):

It started happening to me after I refreshed the spreadsheet page. Silly as it is, **closing the Appscript tab and opening it again worked.**

Comment: I reopened the appscript tab & the sheet just to be safe. Solved.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there is a outage going on with Google Apps Script when running new projects. I can see a couple of people reporting it in Google's [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/239136914).

It looks like it is only affecting new projects but most old projects are running fine. In the meantime you can add more info to the report to bring more attention to it. I have made some tests in 4 different accounts from different organizations and I can confirm I am also affected by this.

---

A couple users are reporting that it started to fix itself, and it looks like clearing cache and cookies from the browser may solve the issue (this is not a definitive solution but may work for you).

Comment: Sorry, clearing the cache and cookies has no effect. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes, that is why I stated it "may" resolve it. It looks like this is affecting everyone and if you check the issue tracker I mentioned, there is a lot of people reporting the same behavior you just reported. I am afraid there is still no report from Google about this. I can also confirm I have the exact same problem in all my accounts too.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. Adding the script ID to the Library seemed to fix it.

Go to the "settings" option in the left menu of the script editor and copy the script id. Then click the plus icon next to the "Library" option and click "look up". Once the script is found, click "add" and run the script.

Comment: But how to get the script id. Please suggest.

Comment: The script id should be in the settings section (the gear icon at the bottom left menu) of the google app script editor.

Comment: Tried that - no change. Closing and reopening both the editor and the the sheet helped though

Answer (score 1):

Only happens with Apps Script-managed Google Cloud Platform projects. Seems okay if you manually set the GCP project with the id using Resources > Cloud Platform Project...

I tried this because mine started with this error:

> We're sorry, there was an unexpected error while creating the Cloud Platform project. Error code DEADLINE_EXCEEDED